# ruby on rails 3.1 move .swf to asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, flash, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to move SWF files to the asset pipeline, and if possible how can this be done?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would recommend putting them in a folder called `app/assets/flash`.

Add this folder to your asset paths:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'flash')
```

They can be referenced like this in your views:

```
asset_path('name_of_swf')
```

The asset_path helper will ensure the correct file is referenced in development and production modes.

Comment: Great great Did not knew you could extend assets paths like that, thx ! For reference you add this config.assets.path << etc in /config/application.rb

Comment: But isn't app/assets only for files that need to be precompiled? A swf is a binary and requires no precompilation.

Comment: Any binary files that are put in the pipeline get a fingerprint added to them so that you can take advantage of far-future headers and client-side caching.

Comment: How would you refer to this in a script?

Comment: asset_path('name_of_file') assuming the file is somewhere in the assets folder. If it is in a folder than you need to include that.