# Rails: embed a flash swf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, asset-pipeline

What's the correct way to embed a flash swf in a rails view?

I see:
image_tag and video_tag but I don't see swf_tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the pipeline then you must use the rails asset helpers to access the file. This is because the file will get a fingerprint added to it in production, so if you hard code it, it won't work.

You can put SWFs in their own directory as [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990393/ruby-on-rails-3-1-move-swf-to-asset-pipeline/8991934#8991934), then do this in the view:

```
<embed src="<%= asset_path('my_flash.swf) %>", any_embed_options />
```

Answer (score 0):

image_tag is just a helper that parses the file_name and calls tag("img"). You can easily write your own helper. Here's an idea to get started

```
/app/helpers/my_view_helper.rb
swf_tag(path)
  "<embed src=\'path/to/resource\' />".html_safe
end
```

Comment: In this answer where does the swf file go? This is for 3.2.5 using new assets pipeline.